# WebBrowser - Get/Read data from generic Tables with no ID, no TagName, no Class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

As title, I'm trying to read data from some tables in a page.

I often use `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById` for lot of similar things, but in this case I'm unable to access data, since in this page all tables are simply defined by `<table class="table">`

Here is what I'm trying to access :

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Ryzen 3000 - Mainstream</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- Table -->
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ryzen 5 3500</th>
                    <td>3.6 - 4.1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ryzen 5 3500X</th>
                    <td>3.6 - 4.1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ryzen 5 3600</th>
                    <td>3.6 - 4.2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ryzen 5 Pro 3600</th>
                    <td>3.6 - 4.2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ryzen 5 3600X</th>
                    <td>3.8 - 4.4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ryzen 5 3600XT</th>
                    <td>3.8 - 4.5</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
    <!--</panel>-->
</div>
```

I searched a lot on the web, but I was unable to found a valid solution.
Does anyone have hints?

Comment: Well, that `<TABLE>` is child of `<div class="panel panel-primary">`. You can parse elements by Tag Name. The `className` is an Attribute of the element. When you get the `<DIV>`, parse by Tag Name its child elements and get the first `<TABLE>` element with the Attribute `className = "table"`. Then parse its child elements with Tag Name `<TR>` and read each `<TH>` and `<TD>` sub-element.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use HtmlAgilityPack and [Xpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) analytical formula.

Sample code:
Query specific `th` label text:

```
    Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Dim path As String = "https://www..."
    Dim web As New HtmlWeb
    doc = web.Load(path)
    Dim node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
   'The text within the fourth <th></th>
    node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='table']//th")(3) 
    Dim st As String = node.InnerText  'Ryzen 5 Pro 3600
```

Query all `tr` text:

```
    Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Dim path As String = "https://www..."
    Dim web As New HtmlWeb
    doc = web.Load(path)
    Dim nodes As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection
    nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='table']//tr")
    For Each node As HtmlNode In nodes
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(node.InnerText)
    Next
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I studied a bit this HTML Agility Pack.

I tried your code, it works fine if I save only my HTML snipped in an empty HTML file, but it dosn't work properly if I try to apply the same VB Code to the entire web page.

I get as result all desidered data, but in a rought view, all in a row.

Since I'm having difficult to adjust it I thought to use some generics regex for catch and reorder data I want, for example, the first regex should catch "Ryzen 5 3500" + all text until "R", then with another VB Code delete the "R", then go on until the last row.

Comment: You can use Regular Expression to intercept the text after grabbing the data.
Please catch first and then intercept.